# Existence of analytic function in unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist an analytic function $f:D\rightarrow D$ with $f(1/2)=3/4$ and $f'(1/2)=2/3$? ($D$ is a unit open disc in complex plane.  Please help

Comment: Look for the Schwartz-Pick theorem.

Answer (score 2):

We have to fulfill the 2 conditions :

$$f(1/2)=3/4 \ \ \text{and} \ \ f'(1/2)=2/3 \ \ \ \  \ (C).$$

Do you know the general formula for a bi-conformal bijection $\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ :

$$f_{\theta,a}(z):=e^{i\theta}\dfrac{a-z}{1-\overline{a}z} \ \ \ \ \implies \ \ \ f'_{\theta,a}(z)=e^{i\theta}\dfrac{|a|^2-1}{(1-\overline{a}z)^2} \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

with a certain $|a|<1$ and a certain $\theta$ ? (the second formula will be needed soon).

Let us use conditions (C):

$$e^{i\theta}\dfrac{a-\tfrac12}{1-\tfrac{\overline{a}}{2}}=\dfrac34 \ \ \text{and} \ \ 
e^{i\theta}\dfrac{|a|^2-1}{(1-\tfrac{\overline{a}}{2})^2}=\dfrac23. \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Thus $$e^{i\theta}=\dfrac34\dfrac{1-\tfrac{\overline{a}}{2}}{a-\tfrac12}=
\dfrac23\dfrac{(1-\tfrac{\overline{a}}{2})^2}{|a|^2-1}. \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$

It remains to find solutions for parameter $a$ using the second equation in (3) taking into account constraint $|a|<1$.

we find that $a$ is the smallest root in absolute value of a certain quadratic, and obtain, all computations done, $a=\dfrac{5+3\sqrt{10}}{13}$.

But plugging this value in equation (3), we get $e^{i\theta}=-1.0405
$ which is hard to fullfill, but at the same time not very far from $-1$.

Thus, one could propose an approximate solution :

$$f(z):=(-1)\dfrac{a-z}{1-za} \ \ \ \ (4)$$

giving ... approximate values instead of the exact values (conditions (C)):

$$f(\tfrac12)=0.72075... \ \text{instead of} \ \ 3/4 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \  f'(\tfrac12)=0.64067... \text{instead of} \ 2/3.$$

Conclusion : strictly speaking, there is no bi-conformal bijection from the disk to itself fullfilling conditions (C).

The (approximate) transformation $f$ we have found can be understood through the image it gives (on the right) of a polar grid (on the left) ; see below :

[image]

---

Important Addendum (following the advice of @Cain) : the Schwarz-Pick theorem gives a short proof that no bi-holomorphic function from the disk to itself can exist fulfilling conditions (C).

In fact, this theorem asserts that the existence of such a function is conditioned by the following inequality :

$$\text{for all} \  z \in \mathbb{D}, \ \ \ \frac{\left|f'(z)\right|}{1-\left|f(z)\right|^{2}}\leq \frac{1}{1-\left|z\right|^{2}}. \ \ \ \ \ (5)$$

But, if one takes $z=\frac12$ with the given values in (condition (C)), we see that (5) is not fulfilled for this value of $z$ because $\frac{32}{21}<\frac{4}{3}$ is erroneous.

Comment: I have added final calculations showing that one can obtain an approximate solution in this way. I provide also a graphical representation.

Comment: I have added at the end a definitive proof of the non existence of a bi-holomorphic function with the given constraints (C) based on the theorem of Schwarz-Pick. Many thanks to @Cain !

Comment: For the inequalities of Schwarz-Pick, I do not think you need bijection. You just need holomorphic of the disc INTO itself. The original question at the top here does not mention bijection. I think your reasoning is fine, however. (I believe that if you assume bi-holomorphicity i.e. automorphism, the first inequality becomes an equality.) WIKI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem

Comment: @311411 Very valuable remark. Thanks!